# Python for loop sum function trouble

Tags: python

Not sure what is wrong with this function but would appriciate any help I could get on it. New to python and a bit confused.

```py
def summer(tables):
    """
    MODIFIES the table to add a column summing the previous elements in the row.

    Example: Suppose that a is

        [['First', 'Second', 'Third'], [0.1, 0.3, 0.5], [0.6, 0.2, 0.7], [0.5, 1.1, 0.1]]

    then place_sums(a) modifies the table a so that it is now

        [['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Sum'],
         [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8], [0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 1.5], [0.5, 1.1, 0.1, 1.7]]

    Parameter table: the nested list to process
    """
    numrows = len(tables)
    sums = []
    for n in range(numrows):
        sums = [sum(item) for item in tables]
        return sums
```

Comment: not clear what you're actually trying to do...but you define sums as [] then define it as the result of a list comprehension every time you loop over numrows and you also return every iteration

Comment: You’ve asked a lot of questions in the last few days, many of them have good answers on them. But you have never marked a single one solved.   You should consider going through those and marking the correct answer so people get credit for helping you.

Comment: You're right I will

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for. You don't need to create a new list. You just need to update your variable `tables`. Also putting a return statement inside your loop just make it run one iteration. You should look at how for loop work and what the return statement actually does.

```
def summer(tables):
    """
    MODIFIES the table to add a column summing the previous elements in the row.

    Example: Suppose that a is

        [['First', 'Second', 'Third'], [0.1, 0.3, 0.5], [0.6, 0.2, 0.7], [0.5, 1.1, 0.1]]

    then place_sums(a) modifies the table a so that it is now

        [['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Sum'],
         [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8], [0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 1.5], [0.5, 1.1, 0.1, 1.7]]

    Parameter table: the nested list to process
    """
    tables[0].append('Sum')
    for i in range(1, len(tables)):
        tables[i].append(sum(tables[i]))
```

Comment: Conin, please try to learn from this answer, and not just run off to slap copy-paste it on other similar problems. I think you should take some time to read these 4 lines, until they read like plain English to you (they are not very far from English to be honest).

Comment: Thank you, you guys are right. I am just trying to teach myself python using online course material I found and the internet. I will try to stop just asking questions to try to learn from responses and fix the problem itself. Adam you are right the response here is actually pretty simple and I understand it all, I just I just immediately went to this website as a crutch. Thanks for waking me up

Comment: @ConinJefferson best of luck! programming is fun, and Python is awesome, I'm sure in a short time you'll be making cool stuff.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.